# Google authentication with fastapi-sso

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, fastapi

I am using fastapi for backend and gonna implement social login using fasapi-sso.

The login process was success.

But I am gonna register the user with google.

Is there any option to register user password with google?

Thank you

I tried with it but I cannot find the password option from fastapi-sso.

```
@router.get("/login/google")
async def google_login():
    """
    Generate login url and redirect
    """
    with google_sso:
        return await google_sso.get_login_redirect()



@router.get("/login/google/callback")
async def google_callback(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db_session)):
    """
    Process login response from Google and return user info
    """
    # Get user details from Google
    google_user = await google_sso.verify_and_process(request)
    
    ...
```